# Jenkins: How do I skip a tests job if the class being tested hasn't changed?

Tags: testing, build, jenkins, conditional-statements, jobs

I'm having a lot of trouble setting up a conditional build job in Jenkins. 
Here's my setup:

I have a series of jobs such as: **JobA <- JobB <- JobC <- JobC-tests**, where **<-** means "produces artifacts for".  So, **JobA** produces artifacts which **JobB** relies on, and so on (read right-to-left, it would mean "depends on").

One of the downstream jobs, lets say **JobC** uses 2 SCM repositories, lets call them fooC and barC. **JobC-tests** has another fileset, called barC-tests.

**JobC-tests** takes a long time. **JobC** is very fast. I want to avoid running **JobC-tests** unless barC or barC-tests have changed.

I'd like to set up my builds to work like this:

1. If fooC changes, build JobC but not JobC-tests.
2. If barC changes, build JobC and then build JobC-tests when JobC finishes.
3. If barC-tests change, build JobC-tests using the last successful JobC artifacts.
4. If JobC is started manually, do not build JobC-tests.
5. If JobC-tests is started manually, do not build JobC.
6. JobC blocks on upstream jobs (JobB).

I tried using the [Conditional BuildStep plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin) but that seems to not work at all for me. I set JobC to exclude barC from SCM triggering, and JobC-tests to poll for barC, with a conditional build step in JobC-tests to only build JobC if triggered by an SCM change. Changes to barC-tests would not trigger any build, which would have been fine if this worked at all.  The problem I had was JobC-tests not triggering JobC at all.

I also tried creating a 'polling' job which polls for changes to barC, then blocks while building JobC followed by building JobC-tests. But, the polling job becomes an upstream job, and since JobC blocks on upstream jobs, I run into deadlock.

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.